# Confusing parts about React and Angular serving

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, web-development-server

I have started to learn React and now I am a bit confused about different parts of development and deployment.

Does all webpages are bild with frameworks like React or Anguler? Or they are used only for one page web applications? Can I serve React with nodejs server?

Does the method when you build static webpage with js, html, css and serving them with Apache web server is still used in modern world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly suggest using the React-Create-App utility.  And yes, you can use Node.js.  In fact, React doesn't force you to use any backend framework.  I could pick ASP.NET MVC, Node, Spring MVC, Rails, etc.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

But this tutorial will guide you through creating react apps in development and creating production builds.

When you build in production, you'll end up with a public folder with html files.  But in React, you don't create html files, you create .jsx, which is a combination of html-like React tags with JavaScript.  They will get transpiled to html, etc during the production build phase.  You can then take the build folder and deploy it on an HTTP server, such as Apache.